# Email security with PCKS11 and Python - send a signed unencrypted email

Tags: email, python, smime, pkcs#11, pkcs#7

What I am trying to achieve:

- send a signed, unencrypted email using a smart card token through a Python script

What I've tried so far:

- Have a look on an incoming email signed with same corporate smart card system. It is a multipart email with an attached signature headers like the following:

```
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"
```

- Sign a text piece using [PyKCS11](https://github.com/LudovicRousseau/PyKCS11/blob/master/samples/signature.py), that is, for a text string and smart card pin code provided the function returns some bytecode.
- Study a S/MIME example from [M2Crypto](https://m2crypto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.smime.html) though it's PCKS7 where I find code like the following:

```
    s = SMIME.SMIME()
    s.load_key('signer_key.pem', 'signer.pem')
    p7 = s.sign(buf, SMIME.PKCS7_DETACHED)
    ..
    s.write(out, p7, buf)
```

What I see so far is:

- SMIME implementation I've found works with PKCS7 object (`p7` is not a string as I thought initially);
- Signed emails contain *x-pkcs7-signature*

Does this mean, the data I get from the PyKCS11 module in this case is not some sort of "pkcs11" signature and I have just to wrap it up as a PCKS7 object either override the SMIME.write() method?

Or, the whole setup might be a wrong way?